# I can not run QZ-Tray if it inside a function on Express

Tags: javascript, express, barcode-printing, qz-tray

I try to make a web app to print on LQ-310 Printer using express and QZ-Tray. However, I cannot execute the printing process as expected, it only triggered to print if users hit the endpoint, if I put the QZ-Tray functions inside another function. I have tried to create a dedicated file for it and execute it using bash/shell script if users trigger the endpoint like this:

```
const printInvoice = (req, res) => {
    fs.writeFile(`src/invoice/invoice.json`, JSON.stringify(req.body), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    // shell script to run qz-tray
    const shell = require('shelljs');
    shell.echo('Running qz-tray');
    shell.exec('bash src/invoice/qz-tray.sh');

    fs.readFile(`src/invoice/invoice.json`, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}
```

However, my terminal return no result, not even error message.

I also have set out to just do it inside one function on route, but found no result.

Note:
[this is my repo for the problem, Rusydy/print-qz](https://github.com/Rusydy/print-qz)

Comment: Hi, where do you intend to run the QZ Tray desktop application?  The server running Express or a PC rendering the web page?

Comment: Hi @tresf I try to create a web app using Express and run the QZ-Tray on it.

Comment: Ok, if you're trying to run QZ Tray on a web page (browser -- e.g. QZ Tray is installed on the PC that's rendering the page), you'll likely have to use the client-side implementation of QZ Tray.  I've posted an example below.  Please excuse my lack of Express experience. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QZ Tray is most commonly a client-side library.  This means that the JavaScript calls must originate from the client (browser), not the server (node).

Here's a very simple boilerplate `layout.jade` to get Express + Jade talking to QZ Tray.  It's built on top of the [express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

- **Note 1:** Please excuse any fundamental app design or templating mistakes below as I don't have experience with Express -- or Jade for that matter.
- **Note 2:** Node/server/backend communication with QZ Tray is supported too, but this combination is much less common.

```bash
# put qz-tray.js in an accessible, public directory
curl -o public/javascripts/qz-tray.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qzind/tray/master/js/qz-tray.js
```

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    /***************************
     * code changes start here *
     ***************************/ 
    script(src='/javascripts/qz-tray.js', type='text/javascript')
    script.
      qz.websocket.connect().then(() => {
        return qz.printers.find()
      }).then(printers => {
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += "<p>Found printers:</p><ul>";
        printers.forEach(printer => {
          document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += "<li>" + printer + "</li>";
        });
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += "</ul>";
      });
    /***************************
     *   end of code changes   *
     ***************************/ 
  body
    block content
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tresf!
Now I have progress on my project. However, I encounter another blocker about certificate and signing. I've watch your tutorial on YouTube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X72y6ZZTWzE&t=777s), but I still have error on setCertificatePromise. I'll upload another question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74032951/11973623